# iOS Share Extension notification

Tags: ios, swift3, notifications, share-extension

I'm developing an application that has a share extension target.
The app allows photo upload to a server which makes some analysis on the photo. When the analysis is done, which may take few seconds, a notification (with a banner) appears to notify the user.

The share extension allows to send photos for analysis directly from the Photo app. But once the photo posted, the extension disappears and I cannot notify the user that the task is over.

Do you know if this is achievable or not? If yes, any hint?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it a push notification?

Comment: Not a push notifications. The app should receive a rest 200 response and display something, like an alert, on the screen.

Comment: I would consider switching to push notifications in your place. I can imagine a few scenarios were either your app gets killed before the server responds or the server takes much more time (more complicated image, a lot of requests to the server) to do its work. Also, this would solve your extension issue, since the notification would be independent from what happens on the device.

Comment: Hi, what about having a progress bar like in WhatsApp share extension, which displays an upload progress bar and an "abort" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to do it. But I needed to use a custom view instead of the initial `SLComposeServiceViewController` view. The code is the following :

```
class ShareViewController: UIViewController {
...
}
```

Note that I have to provide the code to dismiss the view.